# What's difference between io.emit(...) and loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

First of all, I hope you understand my poor english skill.

I'm developing a server using socket.io and server contains all client's 'socket' variable that given as parameter to 'connection'. and I want to broadcast 'message' without all functions of 'io' object. so I plan to implement broadcast function like that.

```
let socketList = [ ... ]; // <-- that array contains socket of client.
for (let i = 0; i < socketList.length; ++i)
    socketList[i].emit(...);
```

but It makes no sence to me. because I don't know that's same with io.emit function. so my question is: Is that code same with io.emit(...)?

Comment: If `socketList` contains all connected clients, yes it's the same.

Comment: @BenFortune so you meant, socket.io loops internally? I want to make sure because performance is quite important in my server computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code and `io.emit()` will do the same thing if all your clients really are in `socketList`. If this is about performance and you don't have to do anything fancy like filtering out certain clients, I would go with `io.emit()`, that way you won't need to keep your own socketList.